# How do I terminate a .pyw background task?

Tags: python

I have created a background task that runs when I run the `.pyw` file. I do not want this background task to run all the time, how can I terminate the process?

here is my code:

```
import time

hostsPath = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_blocked = ("python.org")
while True:
    if 1 == 1:
        print("Website Blocked")
        with open(hostsPath, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for site in website_blocked:
                if site in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + site + "\n")
    else:
        with open(hostsPath, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(site in line for site in website_blocked):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
        print("Website allowed")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: If terminate process in Task Manager isn't satisfying you, You should add some event, eg. from keyboard input or timer, to close your program.

Comment: Please show some code. Right now it isn't clear what exactly you want to ask for (why can't you simply `sys.exit()` from inside the process?)

Comment: I do not see the process in Task Manager

Comment: How are you starting the process?

Comment: I am starting the process by running the .pyw file from File Explorer

Comment: Are you sure that you can't find the process in task manager? (perhaps you need to "show all users", perhaps the process is named "pythonw" instead of "python", something like that)

Comment: No, I am not able to see the process in the task manager. If I was able to do so then there would not be an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux system

```
ps aux | grep python
kill PID
```

On windows user `Tasklist` and `Taskkill` instead.

Comment: Open a cmd, press win+R and input ```cmd```